# How to prevent an unconnected iscsi disk to slow down my pc boot?

Tags: 16.04, boot, services, iscsi

My ubuntu 16.04 bootime is consistently long (several minutes). When i run

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

the first line is

```
 2min 687ms open-iscsi.service
```

The box is indeed setup with an iscsi drive (a separate NAS box) but I keep this drive off 99% of the time which could explain the long boot time.

My question is, how do I setup my system so that the unsuccessful wait for the iscsi connexion does not slow down the boot process?

Things I tried:

I tried to setup the replacement_timeout to -1 in /etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf

```
node.session.timeo.replacement_timeout = -1
```

but it did not prevent the 2 minutes wait time.

EDIT: additional infos

1/ there is no entry in /etc/fstab for that disk

2/ service status gives some info

```
$ service open-iscsi status
● open-iscsi.service - Login to default iSCSI targets
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/open-iscsi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mer. 2017-12-20 13:35:25 CET; 5h 23min ago
     Docs: man:iscsiadm(8)
           man:iscsid(8)
  Process: 1511 ExecStart=/sbin/iscsiadm -m node --loginall=automatic (code=exited, status=8)
  Process: 1500 ExecStartPre=/bin/systemctl --quiet is-active iscsid.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1511 (code=exited, status=8)

déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp iscsiadm[1511]: iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp iscsiadm[1511]: iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: whitebox.target-2, portal: 192.168.0.99,3260].
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp iscsiadm[1511]: iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp iscsiadm[1511]: iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp iscsiadm[1511]: Logging in to [iface: default, target: whitebox.target--1, portal: 192.168.0.99,3260] (multiple)
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp iscsiadm[1511]: Logging in to [iface: default, target: whitebox.target-2, portal: 192.168.0.99,3260] (multiple)
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp systemd[1]: open-iscsi.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=8/n/a
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp systemd[1]: Failed to start Login to default iSCSI targets.
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp systemd[1]: open-iscsi.service: Unit entered failed state.
déc. 20 13:35:25 hippo-camp systemd[1]: open-iscsi.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 2):

WORKAROUND:
A workaround is to disable iscsi service as follows:

```
systemctl disable iscsi.service
systemctl disable iscsid.service
systemctl stop isci.service
systemctl stop iscsid.service
```

A more satisfying solution would be to be able to make the iscsi connexion non blocking for the boot process.

Answer (score 2):

## Intro:

I had (4) Raspberry Pi's running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and as Docker hosts. One of the (4) hosts- "***Host 1***" in this answer- was taking almost 2 minutes longer to boot than the other (3) in the cohort due to `open-iscsi`.

I tried for a quick-win restarting services and rebooting, but problem persisted.

## Short Answer:

The `open-iscsi` cache was causing the problem. I blew it away and this resolve the issue:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/iscsi/nodes
sudo rm -rf /etc/iscsi/send_targets
sudo systemctl reboot
```

The service then rose up very quickly like the other (3) hosts.

## Longer Answer:

To isolate the fault I performed the following troubleshooting:

## Comparative Analysis:

### Service Dependencies Ordering:

Since there were (4) hosts, comparative analysis using `system-analyze plot`- which gives a comprehensive, very granular look into when, where and how long a service rises-up compared to other services- would yield the answer:

```
sudo systemd-analyze plot > host1.svg
sudo systemd-analyze plot > host2.svg
sudo systemd-analyze plot > host3.svg
sudo systemd-analyze plot > host4.svg
```

I SCP'ed these files to my Macbook:

```
scp ubuntu@192.168.X.1:/home/ubuntu/host1.svg .
scp ubuntu@192.168.X.2:/home/ubuntu/host2.svg .
scp ubuntu@192.168.X.3:/home/ubuntu/host3.svg .
scp ubuntu@192.168.X.4:/home/ubuntu/host4.svg .
```

I then right-clicked `open with` for each of the (4) files and chose my web browser. I now had a tab with each of the files I could compare.

All the services were rising-up in the same order, so I was able to exclude an issue like open-iscsi starting before the networking was fully up. So all hosts were loading the same services in the same order. I could thus exclude service ordering dependencies as the culprit.

### Open-iSCSI Config Files:

I next compared the `open-iscsi` config files for eqch of the (4) hosts:

```
/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi
/etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf
```

These only varied in respect to the CHAP autentication settings. Other than that, there was exact parity between all the hosts' open-iscsi config files. So I could exclude inconsistent open-iscsi configuration as being causal.

### The Cache:

I had changed passwords after configuring ***Host 1***. I suspected this could be giving me the grief. So I thought: it's a no-cost solution to blow away the connections cache:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/iscsi/nodes
sudo rm -rf /etc/iscsi/send_targets
sudo systemctl reboot
```

After the reboot I did another `system-analyze plot` for ***Host 1***:

```
sudo systemd-analyze plot > host1-Post-Cache-Delete.svg
```

This revealed the problem was resolved and that problem was duff CHAP or other connection information in the open-iscsi cache.

## Conclusion:

If you're nervous about deleting anything, just do:

```
cp -rp /etc/iscsi/nodes /etc/iscsi/nodes-BACKUP
```

But otherwise, I'd suggest just blowing away the cache rather than going through the lengthy troubleshooting I did; hope this saves other folks wasting their cycles. Easy problemn to resolve once you know how things are broken ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone who stumbles upon this question because of slow iscsi on boot.

In my case it turned out I accidentally added somehow all of my docker ips of  my truenas server when I only wanted the real ip.

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

showed me 2 minutes of iscsi.service

```
journalctl -r | grep iscsi
```

showed me that it was trying to connect to several docker addresses.

```
Jun 05 14:16:40 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.48.228:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.227.35:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.48.228:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.16.0.1:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.175.190:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.99.166:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.176.217:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.0.10:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.211.202:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.227.35:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.48.228:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.175.190:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:29 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.211.202:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.176.217:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.0.10:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.211.202:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.227.35:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.48.228:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.0.1:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.175.190:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.176.217:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
Jun 05 14:16:18 nobara iscsid[1589]: iscsid: connect to 172.17.0.10:3260 failed (Network is unreachable)
```

I found out that I had registered many nodes with

```
sudo iscsiadm -m node
```

I had to delete all of them by using this command on each

```
sudo iscsiadm --mode node --portal 172.17.227.35:3260 --targetname .2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:t -o delete
```